# How to save deque data in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pickle, deque

I have some code written in Python with this line of code in it:

```
user_last3[name].append(score)
```

And I was wondering if you could somehow save this to some sort of database (in Python 3.x) within Python so that I could handle the data previously saved to the database in order to append scores to already existing users and handle the data to print all of it in the program.

I have done some research and found Pickle and JSon databases but my Python programming knowledge isn't very wide and I do not know how to implement them into my code and how to pack and unpack this line of code.

Can anyone help me? (Any help greatly appreciated)

Comment: I would start by writing to a text file

Comment: pickle is easy to use - import pickle; then pickle.dump(your_type, file_handle). This is the most basic for of serialization that wouldn't take you much time to learn. Unless you are looking for something else which would of course be more complex.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use pickle but after you have dumped the data, how do you unpack it to use it in the code?

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is the [*shelve*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module.  It gives a dictionary-like interface to a persistent data store with pickled Python objects.

Here's an example of deques with data that is remembered from session to session:

```
====== RESTART: Shell ======
>>> import shelve
>>> import collections
>>> user_last3 = shelve.open('scores.pickle', writeback=True)
>>> user_last3['mark'] = collections.deque([86, 81, 92], maxlen=3)
>>> user_last3['jane'] = collections.deque([87, 90, 91], maxlen=3)
>>> dict(user_last3)
{'jane': deque([87, 90, 91], maxlen=3), 'mark': deque([86, 81, 92], maxlen=3)}
>>> user_last3.close()

====== RESTART: Shell ======
>>> import shelve
>>> user_last3 = shelve.open('scores.pickle', writeback=True)
>>> user_last3['mark'].append(99)
>>> user_last3['jane'].append(98)
>>> dict(user_last3)
{'jane': deque([90, 91, 98], maxlen=3), 'mark': deque([81, 92, 99], maxlen=3)}
>>> user_last3.close()
```